Unicode look-alikes
I am looking for an easy way to match all unicode characters that look like a given letter. Consider an example for a selection of characters that look like small letter n.
import re
import sys

sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

look_alike_chars = [ 'n', 'ń', 'ņ', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'ŋ', 'ո', 'п', 'ո']
pattern = re.compile(r'[nńņňŉŋոп]')


for char in look_alike_chars:
    if pattern.match(char):
        print(f"Character '{char}' matches the pattern.")
    else:
        print(f"Character '{char}' does NOT match the pattern.")

Instead of r'[nńņňŉŋոп]' I expect something like r'[\LookLike{n}] where LookLike is a token.
If this is not possible, do you know of a program or website that lists all the look-alike symbols for a given ASCII letter?

Whether two characters look the same has more to do with the font being used and your particular criteria than anything Unicode can predefine.

"Confusables" - https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/confusables.jsp?a=%C5%86&r=None

Was there a copy/paste error in your example?  I see two instances of '\u0578'.

I have a script that maps a lot of these special characters to their "normal" Roman alphabet equivalents https://github.com/JRiggles/sluggify-python - I can't say it's an exhaustive mapping, but it should help get you started. The dictionary that might help you is here

Honestly, you may be able to get away with using the _replace_accents() function from sluggify-python

the python standard lib for that task is unicodedata at least for the "latin characters with diacritics" part (first five characters + n). the rest of your set is really subjective

You need to find 1) equivalence sets but Python regex doesn't support POSIX or Perl style equivalence sets. 2) you need in script confusables, 3) you need in script transliterations to target character.. Then build a pattern out of those. They will not get all cases but will get most. 4) handcraft additional characters. I'll try to put together an answer shortly.

I think W3C has also a continuation of the confusable list, but ... the problem is that it is difficult to define one to the other. Is a similar to o? But in Italic (a and o are more similar). 1, I, l (and symbol |) are also on same page (some fonts distinguish better). And then we have all symbols. So it is impossible to make a comprehensible list. So it depends on the purpose: Filter out single characters in a different script.

FWIW the technical term is homoglyph

There is a Python library called Unidecode that will translate some of these special Unicode character to the corresponding ascii character. A code sample should be this:
import unidecode

input_string = "ñ"
clean_string = unidecode.unidecode(input_string) # = 'n'

However, the correspondences are made based on their actual idiom equivalent.
So whenever you want to translate a capital Greek 'PI' (written п), it will return a 'p' because pi is equivalent to a 'p' and not to an 'n'.
Besides there is no publicly available database of such correspondences. Feel free to build one and share it!

It outputs ['n', 'n', 'n', 'n', "'n", 'NG', 'o', 'p', 'o'] for ['n', 'ń', 'ņ', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'ŋ', 'ո', 'п', 'ո']: print(tuple(unidecode.unidecode(ch) for ch in ('n', 'ń', 'ņ', 'ň', 'ŉ', 'ŋ', 'ո', 'п', 'ո')))

Yes, this is why my answer is to build custom correspondences because such database doesn't exist (yet)

There isn't any specific way to achieve this, you'll need to build up a set of characters, and possibly add additional characters automation misses.
You need to find:

equivalence sets [=n=] or [\p{toNFKD=/n/] but Python regular expression engines do not support equivalence sets. So we need to build it.
you need in-script confusables
you need in script transliterations that resolve to the character you are trying to match.

Then build a pattern out of those
I will try to limit the number of packages required, but robust unicode support is needed:
import icu
import regex

To start with we will need some helper functions.
def NFKD(chars):
    normaliser = icu.Normalizer2.getNFKDInstance()
    return normaliser.normalize(chars)
def to_ascii(char):
    transliterator = icu.Transliterator.createInstance('Latin-ASCII')
    return transliterator.transliterate(char)
def single_letter(chars):
    pattern = r'^[\p{sc=Common}\p{sc=Inherited}]*\p{Letter}[\p{sc=Common}\p{sc=Inherited}]*$'
    if regex.match(pattern, chars):
        return chars
    return ''

NFKD() speaks for itself: we need decomposed compatibility sequences that match the target letter.
to_ascii() will asciify and Latin string.
single_letter() will weed out compatibility decompositions or asciification that resolve to two or more letters.
We then define a set of characters we want to restrict our choices from. We aren't interested in lookalikes from other scripts, just Latin, But I will include Inherited and Common scripts as well.
LATIN = set(icu.UnicodeSet(r'[[\p{sc=Latin}][\p{sc=Inherited}][\p{sc=Common}]]'))

We will test our target character against this set using a series of set comprehensions, then create a pattern from the union of those sets:
def get_target_pattern(target):
    equivalence = {x for x in LATIN if target in single_letter(NFKD(x))}
    checker = icu.SpoofChecker()
    checker.setChecks(icu.USpoofChecks.ALL_CHECKS)
    confusable = {x for x in LATIN if checker.areConfusable(target, x) != 0}
    asciified = {x for x in LATIN if target in single_letter(to_ascii(x))}
    return f'[{''.join(set.union(equivalence, confusable, asciified))}]'

For n this gives us:
pattern = get_target_pattern('n')
print(pattern)
# [ňɲｎǹŋṋꞑₙṇꝴƞᶇ⒩ⓝɳⁿṅȵñńņᵰŉnṉꞥ]

Update:
There are a number of ways of modifying the results:

Use NFD instead of NFKD
Add Cyrillic and Greek script confusables

def normalize(chars, nf="nfd"):
    match nf.lower():
        case "nfc":
            form = "nfc"
            mode = icu.UNormalizationMode2.COMPOSE
        case "nfkc":
            form = "nfkc"
            mode = icu.UNormalizationMode2.COMPOSE
        case "nkkc_cf":
            form = "nfkc_cf"
            mode = icu.UNormalizationMode2.COMPOSE
        case "nfkd":
            form = "nfkc"
            mode = icu.UNormalizationMode2.DECOMPOSE
        case "nfd":
            form = "nfc"
            mode = icu.UNormalizationMode2.DECOMPOSE
    normalizer = icu.Normalizer2.getInstance(None, form, mode)
    return normalizer.normalize(chars)

LATN_CODESPACE = set(icu.UnicodeSet(r'[[\p{sc=Latin}][\p{sc=Inherited}][\p{sc=Common}]]'))
LCG_CODESPACE = set(icu.UnicodeSet(r'[[\p{sc=Latin}][\p{sc=Cyrillic}][\p{sc=Greek}][\p{sc=Inherited}][\p{sc=Common}]]'))

def get_target_pattern(target, norm_form = "nfkd", extended=False):
    equivalence = {x for x in LATN_CODESPACE if target in single_letter(normalize(x, norm_form))}
    checker = icu.SpoofChecker()
    checker.setChecks(icu.USpoofChecks.ALL_CHECKS)
    if extended:
        checker.setChecks(icu.USpoofChecks.MIXED_SCRIPT_CONFUSABLE)
        confusable = {x for x in LCG_CODESPACE if checker.areConfusable(target, x) != 0}
    else:
        checker.setChecks(icu.USpoofChecks.WHOLE_SCRIPT_CONFUSABLE)
        confusable = {x for x in LATN_CODESPACE if checker.areConfusable(target, x) != 0}
    asciified = {x for x in LATN_CODESPACE if target in single_letter(to_ascii(x))}
    return f'[{''.join(set.union(equivalence, confusable, asciified))}]'

get_target_pattern('n')
get_target_pattern('n', norm_form="nfd")
get_target_pattern('n', norm_form="nfd", extended = True)


From where are those packages icu and regex? I tried to install PyICU 2.13.1 on Debian via WSL2 but the installation fails with "Could not build wheel for..."

On Ubuntu, for regex i just install it with pip: pip install regex and for PyICU I cloned the gitlab repo and built it. But debian has packages for python-pyicu and python-regex, so that is probably the easiest way for you to install them.
